# How can I configure SSRS 2005 to use ASP.NET 2.0 Forms Authentication?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, forms-authentication

I have an instance of SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services that is outward (internet) facing. I want to enable Forms Authentication using ASP.NET 2.0.  Several web sites discuss how to configure this to work, but none of the instructions lead to a completed solution.  Does someone have consise instructions that are easy to follow and will work?

I'm using Windows Server 2003

Answer (score 1):

Read section "Integrating Reporting Services into an ASP.NET Application" from [MSDN - Best Practices for Configuring Forms Authentication in Reporting Services 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283249(SQL.90).aspx).
You need to change Web.config in both SSRS and ASP.NET application: "...set attributes of the forms and machineKey sections of the Web.config file to the same values for all applications that are participating in shared Forms authentication..."

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms" >
      <!-- The name, protection, and path attributes must match 
           exactly in each Web.config file. -->
      <forms loginUrl="login.aspx"
        name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" 
        protection="All"  
        path="/" 
        timeout="30" />
    </authentication>

    <!-- Validation and decryption keys must exactly match and cannot
         be set to "AutoGenerate". The validation and decryption
         algorithms must also be the same. -->
    <machineKey
      validationKey="C50B3C89CB21F4F1422FF158A5B42D0E8DB8CB5CDA1742572A487D9401E3400267682B202B746511891C1BAF47F8D25C07F6C39A104696DB51F17C529AD3CABE" 
      decryptionKey="8A9BE8FD67AF6979E7D20198CFEA50DD3D3799C77AF2B72F" 
      validation="SHA1" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

See [MSDN - Forms Authentication Across Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc(VS.80).aspx) for details.

Also, install [Reporting Services samples for Microsoft SQL Server 2005 SP2](http://msftrsprodsamples.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4043) and look into "FormsAuthentication Sample"